# Need to transfer data from the table to another template

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have body of my table :

```
<tbody>
@foreach($places as $place)
    @if($place->place_info==0)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><input type="text">{{$place->id}}</th>
            <td>{{$place->vagon_type}}</td>
            <td>{{$place->place}}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" onclick="location.href='https://poizd/train_choose/place_choose/Ticket_form'"
                        class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm m-0 waves-effect">Купити
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

I need to transfer data from  to another template when I click on button.
How I can do it.

Comment: I guess then you have to submit data in form and redirect that data to another template.

Answer (score 0):

You cant send data to another template with out parameter in **`GET`** Method or send over **`POST`** method

```js
onclick="location.href='https://poizd/train_choose/place_choose/Ticket_form'"
```

in get method you can send with `?param1=val1&param2&val2` at the end of url
or send from form method

```html
<form method="post" action='https://poizd/train_choose/place_choose/Ticket_form'>
   <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="val1">
   <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="val2">
   .
   .
   .
   <button> send </button>
</form>
```